# Jython get result from file with sys.exit()

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm trying to fetch a result from a Python script triggered by execfile() from Java (Jython).
This is the java side, which is working (sorry for the not visible static imports):

```
    // prepare script stream:
    String scriptString = scriptProvider.getScriptFile().getRoot().toString();

    Path scriptPath = get(scriptString);
    checkState(exists(scriptPath), "Script file does not exist in %s", scriptString);

    InputStream scriptStream;
    try {
        scriptStream = newInputStream(scriptPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Exception occured while getting InputStream from scriptPath.", e);
    }

    // prepare interpreter and arguments:
    initialize();

    PySystemState state = new PySystemState();
    for (String file : checkFiles) {
        state.argv.append(new PyString(file));
    }

    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter(null, state);

    // execute script:
    interpreter.execfile(scriptStream);
```

Note that I may not change the file which is executed there, I just want to fetch the result that is normally printed when you run it from console. I'm not used to Python, but I think the main output point is:

```
def main():
arguments = parse_command_line_arguments()
set_up_logging(arguments.loglevel)
result = check_files(arguments.files)
sys.exit(result)
```

Especially the last line.
Do you have any ideas how to fetch this from the Java side?